# SwiftUI Grid Layout

Tags: swift, swiftui, vstack, hstack

I'm trying to achieve the following grid layout with SwiftUI but not quite sure on the best approach.

[image]

My code is below and it's not quite getting what I want and also seems hacky to have many nested stacks

```
VStack {
            
            VStack {
                
                HStack {
                    
                    VStack {
                        
                        Text("Text Here")
                        Text("336.851")
                        
                    }
                    .padding(20)
                    .background(ColorManager.orange)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    
                    VStack {
                        
                        Text("Text Here")
                        Text("336.851")
                        
                    }
                    .padding(20)
                    .background(ColorManager.red)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    
                }
                
                HStack {
                    
                    VStack {
                        
                        Text("Text Here")
                        Text("336.851")
                        
                    }
                    .padding(20)
                    .background(ColorManager.green)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    
                    VStack {

                        Text("Text Here")
                        Text("336.851")

                    }
                    .padding(20)
                    .background(ColorManager.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(10)

                    VStack {

                        Text("Text Here")
                        Text("336.851")

                    }
                    .padding(20)
                    .background(ColorManager.purpleLight)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    
                }
                
                
            }
            
        }
```

My code gives the below result, I'm just not sure how I would max the boxes span half and a third of the screen. Also, is the approach I've taken with nested stack the right way?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may try this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                cell(header: "Text Here", text: "336.851", color: Color.orange)
                cell(header: "Text Here", text: "336.851", color: Color.red)
            }
            HStack {
                cell(header: "Text Here", text: "336.851", color: Color.green)
                cell(header: "Text Here", text: "336.851", color: Color.blue)
                cell(header: "Text Here", text: "336.851", color: Color.purple)
            }
        }
    }

    func cell(header: String, text: String, color: Color) -> some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(header)
                    .font(.caption)
                Text(text)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .padding(20)
        .background(color)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .padding(10)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed!  Much less code and spans how I wanted.

Comment: .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) might not be needed thanks to the Spacer() in the cell, but nice answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code for each Box you have.

```
.padding(20)
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity) //This will stretch your Box.
.background(ColorManager.orange)
```